# Double limits and the law of large numbers

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

I'm working on a problem where I have a sequence of n i.i.d. Bernoulli Random variables 
$X_1(n),...,X_n(n)$
where each $X_i(n) = 1$ with some probability $p(n)$ and equal to 0 with probability $1-p(n)$. As $n \to \infty$, I have that $\lim_{n \to \infty} p(n) = p.$

If $p(n)$ was constant and identical to $p$, I could use the strong law of large numbers to say

"For every $\epsilon > 0$ and and every infinite sequence $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$, there exists $N$ such that for all $n \geq N$ we have
$$|\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i - p| < \epsilon"$$

I would like to use an analogous statement that holds when $p$ is not constant, but depends on $n$ and converges to a limit when $n$ is large

""For every $\epsilon > 0$ and and every infinite sequence $\{X_i(j)\}_{i,j=1}^{\infty}$ where $X_i(j)$ is Bernoulli with parameter $p(j)$, there exists $N$ such that for all $n \geq N$ we have
$$|\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i(n) - p(n)| < \epsilon"$$

Is this statement true? Does it follow from the strong law of large numbers?

---

The way I would think of solving this problem is by saying

1. There are a countable number of different p(j)'s
2. The inequality |\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i(j) - p(j)| < \epsilon holds almost surely for each j, as long as n is larger than some $N = N(j)$ which could possibly depend on $p(j)$
3. Since the intersection of a countable number of almost sure events happens almost surely, the inequality holds in particular for for $j = n$ as long as $n \geq N$

The part where the above argument might break is that the condition $n \geq N(j)$ in step 2 could be vacuous. As $j$ gets larger, I might need to choose larger and larger n, so step 3 wouldn't follow from step 2. I don't think this is necessarily true, since $N(j)$ should depend only on p(j), and p(j) is converging.

Comment: So you have a triangular array, the $n$th row of which is i.i.d with its own $p_n?$

Comment: Yes. Without loss of generality (and to better fit the definition of almost sure convergence), it can also be an infinite square array where the n^{th} row is an infinite sequence of iid random variables with its own p_n

Comment: What does Bernstein's inequality tell you about $P(|\overline X_n-p_n|>\epsilon),$ where $\overline X_n $ denotes the average of the first $n$ terms in row $n$?

Comment: It tells me that the probability of $|\overline{X_n}-p_n| < \epsilon$ decreases exponentially with n, where the rate of decrease can be made so as not to depend on $p_n$.

Using that, I can prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} Prob( |\overline{X_n}-p_n| < \epsilon) $ converges to conclude that the events hold almost surely.

Thanks!

Comment: Does your $\bar{X}^{(j)}=\frac1j\sum\limits_{i=1}^jX_i(j), j\ge 1$ be defined on same probability space, it is necessary to discuss your questions. And are $\{\bar{X}^{(j)}, j\ge 1\}$ independent?